# variables, script tags inside a markup fetched from external source not rendered reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React component is pulling HTML from external source. Few APIs are able to render the HTML part, but if we try to have a variable or script in that HTML, that is not working. Tried few things. Following is render method of component

```
render(){
        const varInside = 'Some Variable Inside';
        return (<div>
                <script>console.log('Hello inside render');</script>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.htmlContent}} />
                <div>React HTML Parser - { ReactHtmlParser(this.state.htmlContent)}</div>
                <div>React to HTML - { htmlToReactParser.parse(this.state.htmlContent)}</div>
                <div>Raw content - { this.state.htmlContent }</div>
            </div>)   
 }
```

`htmlContent` variable is pulled form external source using call, following is present in this variable.

```
<h2>This is a HTML fragment {varInside}</h2>
<script>console.log('Hello from fragment');</script>
```

The `varInside` is not getting replaced. Tried few options to convert HTML to react markup

1. API provided by [react to set HTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)
2. React HTML parser is using npm module [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)
3. React to HTML is using npm module [react-to-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react)

We get output something like

[image]

Also the `script` tag `console.log` is not getting called whether its inside `render` method or part of html coming from external source. If there a JS function which is part of markup, present in some other JS library, we were checking if that can get executed.

Having said that, why we are trying to do this (as this might not be right approach). We were evaluating a use case where HTML markup is fetched from a different CMS server and used in react components. There would be some pros and cons of trying to integrate reactjs with CMS (CMS work in traditional manner of every page being seperate page, while reactjs is a SPA based framework). But first we are first evaluating different options (exposing JSON instead of markup from CMS might be one option). Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the example you posted? It looks like it's rendering the html content each time? And I've never seen a script injected into a component like that, not sure if that'll work.

Comment: Ah, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` expects an object with a `string` value. Try converting `this.state.htmlContent` to a string when setting it as the value: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.htmlContent.toString() }} />`

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Yes we were trying to render same HTML using different methods to see if it respects the variable or script tags. Tried using `.toString()` also, it gives same result

Comment: @sandeep : I would suggest you to expose the AEM/CMS server using JSON content instead of Complete HTML Markup.

The current approach looks too complicated and error prone.. You won't be able to leverage the ReactJS benefits itself, apart from just ending up with SPA.

I am using the JSON approach in our large scale E-Commerce site, and it's working like charm.

Comment: After doing some tests, the script tag is what is breaking this. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/88227/. You have a couple issues with your code, if you aren't storing it as a string then you will get errors because it is invalid JSX. No matter what I did, couldn't get the script tag to work. You should look into react-helmet and you can dynamically add script tags to the head. What you're trying to do here won't work out of the box with React.

Comment: And here's a version using straight JSX (recommended) https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/88228/